# Identifying N47K63

Tags: components, identification

Who knows what K63 means? I think it comes from an old Philips CRT.

It looks like a blue capacitor
It says: N47K63

I think N47 stands for 47 nanoFahrad, but what can K63 mean?

[image]

Comment: N47 usually does not mean 47 nF, but 47K can mean 47000 pF which is 47 nF, 63 means 63 Volts. So My guess is that this is a 47 nF, 63 V capacitor. I'd use an MKT model if it needed to be replaced.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you ... I don't need to replace it, the CRT was fully dead. It's my first salvage project and just don't recognize all components (so I learn by asking what it is). I couldn't find it by searching on google.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie -- make that an answer and I'll upvote it

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I will upvote it too of course, your remark is exactly the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N47 usually does not mean 47 nF, but 47K can mean 47000 **pF** which is 47 nF.

63 means 63 Volts maximum voltage. Since it is not written that that is AC, assume it is DC so the maximum voltage is 63 V DC. Although that sounds like an odd value, it is often used.

So My guess is that this is a 47 nF, 63 V capacitor. I'd use an MKT model if it needed to be replaced.